# React Testing With Jest - Mock components on the same file except one

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a `tsx` file which contains three react components:

```
import {FC} from 'react';

export const ComponentA: FC<{booleanProp: boolean}> = ({booleanProp}) => {
    return (
        <>
            {booleanProp ? (
                <ComponentB />
            ) : (
                <ComponentC />
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export const ComponentB: FC = () => {
    return <span>ComponentB</span>;
};

export const ComponentC: FC = () => {
    return <span>ComponentC</span>;
};
```

I want to test `ComponentA` and mock `ComponentB` and `ComponentC`.

This is my test file:

```
import {FC} from 'react';
import {createRoot, Root} from 'react-dom/client';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import {ComponentA} from './my-components';

jest.mock('./my-components', () => {
    const ComponentBMock: FC = () => {
        return <span>ComponentB Mock</span>;
    };
    const ComponentCMock: FC = () => {
        return <span>ComponentC Mock</span>;
    };
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('./my-components'),
        ComponentB: ComponentBMock,
        ComponentC: ComponentCMock,
    };
});

describe('ComponentA', () => {
    let container: Element | null = null;
    let root: Root | null = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        root = createRoot(container);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        act(() => {
            root?.unmount();
            root = null;
        });
        container?.remove();
        container = null;
    });

    it('should render "ComponentB" when booleanProp is true', () => {
        act(() => {
            root?.render(<ComponentA booleanProp={true}/>);
        });

        expect(container?.textContent).toEqual('ComponentB Mock');
    });

    it('should render "ComponentC" when booleanProp is false', () => {
        act(() => {
            root?.render(<ComponentA booleanProp={false}/>);
        });

        expect(container?.textContent).toEqual('ComponentC Mock');
    });
});
```

The problem is that the mocks doesn't seem to take effect and these are the tests result:

```
Expected: "ComponentB Mock"
Received: "ComponentB"

Expected: "ComponentC Mock"
Received: "ComponentC"
```

When I debugged the jest mock callback it appears to be called twice. In the first time the `requireActual` returned `undefined` for every component, and in the second time it has the real components values.

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with it and read more about mocking this solution solved my problem.

The difference is the way I import my components and used `jest.spyOn` to mock them:

```
import * as MyComponents from './my-components';

const ComponentA = MyComponents.ComponentA;
jest.spyOn(MyComponents, 'ComponentB').mockReturnValue(<span>ComponentB Mock</span>);
jest.spyOn(MyComponents, 'ComponentC').mockReturnValue(<span>ComponentC Mock</span>);
```

Of course that if you you need to remove the created mock you can restore the mock by calling the `spy.mockRestore` function.

The full test file:

```
import {createRoot, Root} from 'react-dom/client';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import * as MyComponents from './my-components';

const ComponentA = MyComponents.ComponentA;
jest.spyOn(MyComponents, 'ComponentB').mockReturnValue(<span>ComponentB Mock</span>);
jest.spyOn(MyComponents, 'ComponentC').mockReturnValue(<span>ComponentC Mock</span>);

describe('ComponentA', () => {
    let container: Element | null = null;
    let root: Root | null = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        root = createRoot(container);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        act(() => {
            root?.unmount();
            root = null;
        });
        container?.remove();
        container = null;
    });

    it('should render "ComponentB" when booleanProp is true', () => {
        act(() => {
            root?.render(<ComponentA booleanProp={true}/>);
        });

        expect(container?.textContent).toEqual('ComponentB Mock');
    });

    it('should render "ComponentC" when booleanProp is false', () => {
        act(() => {
            root?.render(<ComponentA booleanProp={false}/>);
        });

        expect(container?.textContent).toEqual('ComponentC Mock');
    });
});
```